# How to remove instantiated function related to specific object

Tags: jquery

i can't find out the solution for this simple sample code. It's a continous animation on several DOM objects, needs to be deleted when hover is off from each of them. How to remove instantiated functions? Thanks in advance!

```
var animBorderColor = function(targetElement, color, speed){
    $(targetElement).animate(
    {
        borderColor: 'rgba('+color+','+color+','+color+', 0.7)'
    }, 
    { 
    duration: speed, 
    complete: function(){
        if ( color == '100' ) { color = '200'; } else { color = '100';
        }
            animBorderColor(this, color, speed);
        }
    }
    );
};

$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#obj1").hover(
    function(){
        animBorderColor($(this), '100', 500);
    },
    function() {
        // ?? remove function instantiated above
    });

    $("#obj2").hover(
    function(){
        animBorderColor($(this), '100', 500);
    },
    function() {
        // ?? remove function instantiated above
    });
});
```

EDIT: [Jsfiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/dafj7/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the best way to approach this is with intervals. You can set an interval to animate, and then clear that interval to stop the animation.

Also, since you're trying to animate colors, make sure you are using jQuery UI also.

sample code:

```
function borderAnimate() {
    var color = $(this).css('borderTopColor').indexOf('rgba(100') > -1 ? 'rgba(200,200,200,0.7)' : 'rgba(100,100,100,0.7)';
    $(this).animate({
        borderTopColor: color,
        borderLeftColor: color,
        borderBottomColor: color,
        borderRightColor: color
    }, 500);
}
$('div').hover(function () {
    $this = this;
    window.loop = setInterval(function () {
        borderAnimate.call($this);
    }, 500);
}, function () {
    clearInterval(window.loop);
});
```

and here's a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zTnW2/)

Comment: Nice idea, but what if the selector is for example a class giving more objects back?

    `$(".bordecolorchange").hover(
    function(){
        animBorderColor($(this), '100', 500);
    },
    function() {
        // ?? remove function instantiated above
    });`

Comment: then you could push them to an array.
`var x = [];`
`x.push(animBorderColor($(this), '100',500));`
you could even store the position of the array by grabbing the length of the array before pushing, and storing that index in the element's data attribute if you wanted to selectively remove the instances.

Comment: Maybe it's my fault, but the function's variable is undefined, so the solution above is not perfect. Not working for me, however the idea is perfect. Did I miss something in the function itself?

`var x = animBorderColor($(this), '100', 500);`
`console.log(x); //gives undefined`

The array pushing makes sense perfectly.

Comment: are you limited in that you have to approach the animation this way? It seems you could achieve the same goal using jQuery without the need for a recursive function.

Comment: Not really, just don't have any other idea for continous animation. Plus it's so frustrating to being set back like this. ;)